# Почему `val a: List<Any> = ArrayList<Int>()` корректный код

Tags: java, kotlin

Если я напишу следующий код:

```
    val a: List<Any> = ArrayList<Int>()
    val a2: ArrayList<Any> = ArrayList<Int>() // compile error
```

вторая строчка ожидаемо не скомпилируется, но на мое удивление с первой все OK. Насколько мне известно, в `Java` так сделать бы не вышло:

```
    List<Object> a = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // compile error
    ArrayList<Object> a2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // compile error
```

Почему Котлин допускает такое поведение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Котлине интерфейс List неизменяемый и поэтому его сделали инвариантным

```
public interface List<out E> : Collection<E>
```

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#variance,
https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/reference/generics.html

В Java интерфейс List изменяемый, да и объявлять вариативность на уровне классов и интерфейсов нельзя